# When trading certified items, do they lose status?

Tags: steam, rocket-league

I have a certified item in veteran status. When I trade it to someone else, will it lose that status?

I've not traded a certified item with status yet, but I have traded a certified item with "points" counted towards the status. Those points get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a certified item in veteran status. When I trade it to someone
>   else, will it lose that status?

Yes, the item loses it's status after it gets traded.

**Left:** Before
**Right:** After I traded to another account.

[image]